# Submit Button Calling A Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, methods, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to update a device attribute (lastChangedBy) that will set its value to the user's IP address whenever the submit button is clicked. I wanted to do something like:

```
 <%= form_for(@device) do |f| %>
 .
 .
 .
 <%= if click? ( f.submit "Commit Entries", class: "btn btn-primary" ) == true %>    
      <%= @device.lastChangedBy = request.remote_ip %>
 <% end %>
```

but I don't think that's possible. I'm looking into using "button_to" but after searching online I am extremely confused to how to use it. I tried doing something like:

```
 <%= button_to "Commit Entries", action: "setIp" %>
```

and then in DevicesController & in the helper.rb (because I wasn't sure where it would call the method) I made a simple method:

```
 def setIp
      Device.find(params[:id])
  @device.lastChangedBy = request.remote_ip
 end
```

but I am completely lost. Could someone please help me. It would be amazing if you were specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already submitting a form, and want to set that parameter, do it in the controller:

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    @device.last_changed_by = request.remote_ip # Tada!
    if @device.update_attributes(params[:device])
      redirect_to @device
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

end
```

Tweak according to your application, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are unsure of how to utilize calling a function with button_to, and that you already have a method in your controller you can approach it as follows, by adding some fields to your view's button_to. With this approach you'll also be able to remove your form.

```
=button_to 'SetIp', {:controller => "your_controller", 
     :action => "setIp", :id => your_model.id}, {:method => :post }
```

And in your routes.rb

```
resources :your_controller do    
    post :setIp, :on => :collection    
end
```

And in your_controller.rb

```
def setIp
    device = Device.find(params[:id])
    device.lastChangedBy = request.remote_ip
    device.save!

    #Can redirect to anywhere or render any page
    redirect_to action: :index
end
```